# How to add an extra field in file upload widget?

Tags: 7, entities, files

I know that it is possible to enable a description field in the core file upload widget for Drupal 7.

However, I want to add an *extra* description field like the one already present. For this I've spent hours googling, but not found the perfect solution. Please, someone, help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module might be a great way to do what you want. The [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module is a module that creates fieldable files. Try to read the module description, hope it helps you.

> File entity provides interfaces for managing files. It also extends
>   the core file entity, allowing files to be fieldable, grouped into
>   types, viewed (using display modes) and formatted using field
>   formatters. File entity integrates with a number of modules, exposing
>   files to Views, Entity API, Token and

UPDATE now you want to add an entity reference field on your content type that references your custom file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84573/discussion-on-answer-by-jdrupal-how-to-add-an-extra-field-in-file-upload-widget).